# Javascript checking if form is null

Tags: javascript, forms, html, function

I am very new to Javascript so please be patient. I have a script that is to check if certain form elements are null. If any of the form elements are null, an alert should be shown. However, nothing happens. I have looked at a copious amount of examples, cannot seem to get past this problem.

The script in question is shown below:

```
var age;
var todaysDate;
var birthDate;
var inputOk;

function setDates() {
    if (d.value !== null && m.value !== null && y.value !== null) {
    inputOk = true;

    var day = d.value;
    var month = m.value + 1;
    var year = y.value;
    var today = new Date();
    var dob = new Date(year, month, day);

    todaysDate = today.valueOf();
    birthDate = dob.valueOf();
}
else {
    inputOk = false;
}   
}

function calculateAge() {

}

function outputAge() {
    //var output = document.getElementById('ageOut');
    //document.write('You are aged: '+age);
}

function getAge() { 
setDates();

if (inputOk) {
    calculateAge();
    outputAge();    
}
else {
    alert("Please enter your D.O.B correctly.");
}  
}
```

The HTML form in question is shown below:

```
<form name ="dob" id="dobform">
   <select id="d">
 <option value="null">Day</option>
   </select>
   <select id="m">
 <option value="null">Month</option>
   </select>
   <select id="y">
 <option value="null">Year</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" value="Get my age!" onclick="getAge();"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing your dom elements directly by id is a bad idea.  I believe it will work on some versions of IE, but the standard way is to call `document.getElementById("idOfYourControl")`

So to get the value of your "m" select:

```
var mSelect = document.getElementById("m");
mSelect.value;
```

So your function would look like:

```
function setDates() {
    var dSelect = document.getElementById("d");
    var mSelect = document.getElementById("m");
    var ySelect = document.getElementById("y");

    if (dSelect.value !== "null" && mSelect.value !== "null" && ySelect.value !== "null") {
        inputOk = true;

        //and so on
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I shall remember this in the future.

Comment: It is far better access form controls as named properties of the form as direct property access is faster and more convenient. It also places the control in the context of the form in the code so that the relationship is obvious.

Comment: @Rob, you mean `var f = document.get..ById("dobform");` then `f.d`, `f.m`, and `f.y`?

Answer (score 4):

The value of your input is going to be the string `"null"`, not a real `null` value. Add quotes around your `null`s.

Also, accessing inputs via just their `id`s is bad practice, and I'm not sure if it's even cross-browser compatible. Use the `document.getElementById` function to find your elements instead.

Finally, (unless my memory fails me) the `value` property of `select` elements isn't supported on all browsers currently in use. Better use `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value`.

Comment: Thankyou very much. As I said, all new to me.

Comment: To confirm: Accessing inputs by their id is definitely not cross browser compatible. IE does it, but I think only in quirks mode. Most other browsers don't.

Comment: It works in at least a few browsers (IE, Chrome) but is definitely unstandard and not recommended.

Comment: Using selectedIndex to get a select's value dates back to Navigator 5, I doubt very much that it's still in use. Certainly any site using a modern "cross browser" library will be dysfunctional for very many other reasons.

Comment: @RobG: I can't remember the history, but at least jQuery seems to still use selectedIndex to access the value (while I don't consider the jQuery source a source of absolute truths, I'd imagine their code is tested way better than any of mine will ever be)

Comment: jQuery uses *selectedIndex* because it has a generic function for getting the value of single or multiple selects and dealing with IE's buggy option value property. That isn't required in this case since all the options have a value attribute and using selectedIndex doesn't fix the buggy value property without further effort. In other words, it's doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a script that is to check if certain form elements are null.

Form elements are never "null", though an element that is a form control might not have a value (or more correctly, the value might be an empty string), which is more or less equivalent to being "null".

In your HTML you have:

```
> <form name ="dob" id="dobform">
>     <select id="d">
>        <option value="null">Day</option>
>    </select>
```

Note that in HTML 4.01 (the current HTML standard) for a control's value to be sent when the form is submitted, it **must** have a name, so I would replace the id attribute with a name attribute and use a more helpful value than "d" ("day" seems reasonable).

Also, it is common in browsers that if no option has the *selected* attribute, the first option is made the selected option (though this is not required by the HTML standard and might not be true for all browsers). So in many browsers, the value of the *d* select will always be "null", though it can programmatically be set to some other value. If you want to make sure the first option is the default, then give it the selected attribute:

```
   <select name="day">
     <option value="null" selected>Day
     <!-- more options -->
   </select>
```

It is considered good practice to access form controls as named properties of the form. To test if the user has selected some value other than the default, you can use a test like (assuming the select with id="d" has name="day"):

```
var form = document.getElementById('dobform');

if (form.day.value == 'null') {
  // the control with name "day" has a value of the string "null"
}
```

The other controls should be treated the same way.